# Getting type error undefined object in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to output the data inside render() but I am getting error why so ?

Code:

```
render() {

        let marketing_plan_projects = [];

        marketing_plan_projects = this.props.markets.data ? this.props.markets.data : null;
        let marketing_updates = get_marketing_updates_from_projects(marketing_plan_projects);

        console.log(marketing_updates);

        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

                <Text>{marketing_updates[0].project_name}</Text>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
```

I also tried this: (still gives error)

`<Text>{marketing_updates ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: ""}</Text>`

console.log(marketing_updates) is :

[image]

I am getting following error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your marketing_updates object is not empty ?

Comment: @R.Duteil Initially it is empty(see in screenshot) but then re rendering happens so it gets populated.

Comment: Your error is thrown because at first you have an empty array. react-native can't know that at some point you will actually have data there.

You could do what you have already tried with some modifications:
`<Text>{marketing_updates && marketing_updates.length > 0 ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: ""}</Text>`

Comment: @AndreiOlar Works like a charm thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
marketing_updates ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: ""
```

does not test if the array is empty, but just if it exists. Testing `marketing_updates =  []` will return true, as it is a **truthy value**.

See here for more informations : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Thus you can have an existing array but an undefined value for `marketing_updates[0]` as it might be empty.

To avoid your error, try this instead:

```
marketing_updates.length != 0 ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: ""
```

Comment: If I want to inject the data into FlatList how can I do that ? Is this correct -> `data={marketing_updates && marketing_updates.length > 0 ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: null }`

Comment: This will send marketing_updates' first element's project_name if there is at least one element, null otherwise as data.

Comment: So I am just asking is this correct way -> `data={marketing_updates && marketing_updates.length > 0 ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: null }` to pass data to FlatList considering the situation in my question.

Comment: It depends on what you need to pass as data to your FlatList. If you need the project_name of the first element, then yes, it is the correct way

Comment: Check this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589997/how-to-display-data-using-flatlist-in-react-native