# How to display data using FlatList in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created cardView but how can I convert it to `<FlatList/>` I am not able to understand what should be the `renderItem` of `FlatList` ?

My current code:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.cardView}>
                    <Text style={styles.projectName}>{marketing_updates.length != 0 ? marketing_updates[0].project_name: ""}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{marketing_updates.length != 0 ? marketing_updates[0].title: ""}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>Description: {marketing_updates.length != 0 ? marketing_updates[0].description: ""}</Text>
                    <Image
                    style={styles.img}
                    source={{uri: marketing_updates.length != 0 ? marketing_updates[0].image: null}}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.buttons}>
                        <Text style={styles.like}>Like</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.share}>Share</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.comment}>
                        <Text>Comments: </Text>
                        <Text>comment 1</Text>
                        <Text>comment 2</Text>
                        <Text>comment 3</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
```

How can I convert it to FlatList ?

What I tried :

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                data={marketing_updates.length != 0 && marketing_updates ? marketing_updates : null}
                renderItem={}
                />

            </ScrollView>
```

I am not able to understand what should be there inside `renderItem={}` ?

Comment: I understand that the first block of code is the CardView component and you are treating it as a react component right?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I want each list item to display project_name, title, description, image etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderItem` accepts a function which takes the current list item as an argument and renders a component. You can think of it as the "map" function like in `listItems.map(item => <MyListItem {...item} />`.

I'd recommend you create a presentational "card" component to encapsulate the view rendering logic (e.g. `MarketingUpdateCard`) and just pass the list item data as props:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <MarketingUpdateCard {...item} />
)}
```

And an example card component:

```
// MarketingUpdateCard.js
const MarketingUpdateCard = ({ project_name, title, description, image }) => (
    <View>
      // your current card template here
    </View>
)
```

Comment: I want each list item to display project_name, title, description, image etc

Comment: Yep, that's what is going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

The `renderItem` prop should be a function that returns a react-native component

See there : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem

```
data={marketing_updates}
renderItem = {
    (update) => {
        <Text>
           update.project_name
        </Text>
    }
}
```

The `renderItem()` method will be called for each element of your `marketing_updates` array.

Comment: But I need to check if `marketing_updates` length is non zero or not ?

Comment: So the data should be `data={marketing_updates.length != 0 && marketing_updates ? marketing_updates : null}` am I right ?

Comment: You can pass it a zero lengthed array, it willl call renderItem() zero time because your array will contain zero element, and it won't throw an error

Comment: I want each list item to display project_name, title, description, image etc

Answer (score 1):

According to the react-native docs the "renderItem" does the following:

> Takes an item from data and renders it into the list.

So you can pass any kind of react component to it and the flat list will use this component as for every item inside your list. In your case you can do the following:

move your "CardView" to a new Component called for example "CardViewComponent".

Then you can do following to create a flatlist:

```
<FlatList
  data={marketing_updates.length != 0 && marketing_updates ? marketing_updates : null}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    <CardViewComponent marketingData={marketing_updates[item.index]}/>
  }}
/>
```